# Harmfull suggested edit got approved

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just re-edited an approved suggested edit, which made my answer wrong. Is there a better way to undo these things?

https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/338370

Comment: You can roll back an edit from the edit history (click on the "Edited X minutes ago"). By the way, you might want to simplify that answer, there's no reason to test whether a dir exists before adding it to $PATH.

Comment: Thanks, I did that now :) The way I added the path I copied from a 14.04 .profile file. I wasn't sure which version that guy had and therefore I told him to put that there if it wasn't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If somebody edits something incorrectly, roll it back. Perhaps leave a comment if you think it needs explaining.

If there was a failing in the system that's supposed to stop bad edits, do as you have and post on meta. I can see what they *thought* they were doing (confusing `/home/` with `$HOME`) but the system failed here.

It's a shame that there was no custom reject reason given. If you're faced with something like that (which takes a little brainwork to unravel) **spell it out** in your rejection reason so the next person doesn't have to wake up to work out what to do.

I'll ping a few people a few emails about being more careful. Thanks for raising this.

Comment: Alright, thanks for taking care.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, it was a mistake. I'll be more careful and won't try to edit/approve two posts at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

It's clearly a mistake (I also approved the edit). Sorry I didn't pay enough attention to your post. Actually I edited the other answer after reviewing this suggested edit with the same proposal but in that case the edit was justified (`/home` instead of `$HOME`)

I made a confusion between both answers. Again I apologize for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

As one of those who approved this edit, I thought `crs` was the application folder. IIRC your answer (add `~/bin` to `PATH`) is already applied in the `.profile` on a standard Ubuntu install.

Comment: Well that wasn't my full answer, was it? Also, as I already noted in a comment on this question, I didn't know for how many Ubuntu versions ~/bin has already bin appended to the PATH for, so I went the safe route by asking that guy to check that for me.

Comment: @Bernd mistakes happen. Move on.

Comment: I'm not offended, so sure :)